# Get the user token after calling turnContext.SendActivityAsync with an OAuthCard

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I am using the following code to try and get a user token in my teams app, SSO is configured and administrator grant is given, so the users do not see any prompt. When calling this code:

```cs
protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var userTokenClient = turnContext.TurnState.Get<UserTokenClient>();
    var prompt = Activity.CreateMessageActivity();
    var tokenResponse = await userTokenClient.GetUserTokenAsync(turnContext.Activity.From.Id, _connectionName, turnContext.Activity.ChannelId, null, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

    if (turnContext.Activity.Text.Equals("logout"))
    {
        await userTokenClient.SignOutUserAsync(turnContext.Activity.From.Id, _connectionName, turnContext.Activity.ChannelId, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("You have been signed out."), cancellationToken);
        return;
    }

    if (tokenResponse == null)
    {
        var signInResource = await userTokenClient.GetSignInResourceAsync(_connectionName, (turnContext.Activity as Activity), "", cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        var value = signInResource.SignInLink;
        prompt.Attachments.Add(new Attachment
        {
            ContentType = OAuthCard.ContentType,
            Content = new OAuthCard
            {
                Text = "Test2",
                ConnectionName = _connectionName,
                Buttons = new[]
                {
                    new CardAction
                    {
                        Title = "Test3",
                        Text = "Test1",
                        Type = ActionTypes.Signin,
                        Value = value
                    },
                },
                TokenExchangeResource = signInResource.TokenExchangeResource,
                TokenPostResource = signInResource.TokenPostResource
            },
        });

        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(prompt, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        var hebbenwetokenhier = await userTokenClient.GetUserTokenAsync(turnContext.Activity.From.Id, _connectionName, turnContext.Activity.ChannelId, null, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        // This stays null
        return;
    }
    // Other code here that uses the userToken
}
```

In the variable `hebbenwetokenhier` I would like to get the user token, since the user is not seeing any prompt, I should not need to use another prompt? Can I make sure the OnMessageActivity is called again after receiving the result of sending the OAuthCard? Or is there another way to do this WITHOUT making use of dialogs.

When I run this code, the first time I enter the `tokenResponse == null` check, but after running the OAuthCard once, the user is authenticated and I get a result from line 5, now I just want to make it so the user does not have to send two messages!

Answer (score 0):

you can use the OnInvokeActivityAsync method to receive the invoke activity from the Teams client. This method is called when the user interacts with the OAuthCard and the token exchange process is completed. You can then get the user token in this method.

```
protected override async Task<InvokeResponse> OnInvokeActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IInvokeActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    JObject value = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(turnContext.Activity.Value.ToString());
    JObject authentication = null;
    if (value["authentication"] != null)
    {
        authentication = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(value["authentication"].ToString());
        var userTokenClient = turnContext.TurnState.Get<UserTokenClient>();
        var tokenResponse = await userTokenClient.GetUserTokenAsync(turnContext.Activity.From.Id, _connectionName, turnContext.Activity.ChannelId, null, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        if (tokenResponse != null)
        {
            // Use the user token here
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

OnInvokeActivityAsync method is overridden to handle the invoke activity. The authentication object is extracted from the activity value. If the authentication object is not null, it means that the user has interacted with the OAuthCard and the token exchange process is completed. The GetUserTokenAsync method is then called to get the user token.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the initial reply. The problem here is that I would not know how I get my IMessageActivity in this OnInvokeActivity Call, how do I pass the Message Text along with the function? Tried with ConversationState but could not get it working

Comment: added  answer for this query .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass the message text from a message activity to the OnInvokeActivityAsync method, you could consider using the TurnState property of the turnContext object. The TurnState is a dictionary that allows you to share data within a single turn of conversation.
example of this:

```
protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // Save the message text in the TurnState
    turnContext.TurnState["messageText"] = turnContext.Activity.Text;
    // Continue with your message handling logic...
}
protected override async Task<InvokeResponse> OnInvokeActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IInvokeActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // Retrieve the message text from the TurnState
    var messageText = turnContext.TurnState.Get<string>("messageText");
    // Continue with your invoke handling logic...
}
```

when a message activity is received, the OnMessageActivityAsync method saves the message text in the TurnState. Then, when an invoke activity is received, the OnInvokeActivityAsync method retrieves the message text from the TurnState

This will only work if the message activity and the invoke activity are part of the same turn of conversation.